# Upgrading from sonarqube 4.4 to 4.5.1

Tags: upgrade, sonarqube

I'm upgrading sonarqube from v 4.4 to v 4.5.1 (regarding upgrade guide from sonar website). When I trying to lunch web server it stops suddenly. Did I miss something in conf file?

See command line screen -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHqMX.png

Comment: Please look in logs/sonar.log (or similar) for errors.

Comment: [Here's log](http://shrib.com/GU8UW7PV)

Comment: OK, well the two obvious errors are `ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]]  Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Found two files for the same plugin 'findbugs': sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.0.jar and sonar-findbugs-plugin-2.4.jar` and `ERROR web[jruby.rack]  initialization failed
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: java.lang.NullPointerException`, aren't they? The first may trigger the second but that's not obvious to me.

Comment: So in the first instance please look in extensions/plugins/ and work out why you have two versions of the findbugs plugin, and try removing one.

Comment: Not sure why I had two versions of findbugs, but removing one helped and finally I've got sonar updated. Thanks for help!